# How to convert RGB string into Hex string

Tags: c#, hex, rgb

I need to convert RGB into Hex code.

I have color in the string format `"RGB(r, g, b)"` and I need to convert it in  `"#000000"`.

To example, for `"rgb(208,2,27)"` the output should be `"#D0021B"`

Comment: How do I separate r, g, b  from this string?

Comment: input is  "rgb(208,2,27)" and output should be #D0021B

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting from RGB ints to Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354892/converting-from-rgb-ints-to-hex)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string test = "RGB(208,2,27)";

// Remove "RGB(" and ")", then split remainder by "," and parse into an int array.

var rgb = test.Substring(4, test.Length - 5).Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

// Create Color object from RGB components.

Color colour = Color.FromArgb(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);

// Convert colour into HTML colour string.

string result = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(colour);

Console.WriteLine(result); // Outputs "#D0021B"
```

To compile this code, you will need to reference "System.Drawing" and add "using System.Drawing;" and "using System.Linq;"

Answer (score 0):

use the string.Format like this, where r, g b, are your values,

```
 string.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", r, g, b)
```

Comment: How do I get these r, g b  values from this "RGB(r, g, b)" ?

Comment: how do you get this? please be clear? is it a c# function etc what?